# Can the equation $f''(x)+cf'(x)+g(x)f(x)=0$ be solved for $f(x)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

If we have a differential equation

$$f''(x)+cf'(x)+g(x)f(x)=0,$$

where $c$ is some fixed constant, can we solve for $f(x)$ given an input $g(x)$, and how?

Is it possible to find a formula for $f(x)$ depending on $g(x)$? Whether that is an integral expression, Fourier series, or otherwise?

It is easy enough to solve when $g(x)$ is a constant, for example, and this is a basic equation for a damped oscillator, but I am wondering about how to go about solving if we let $g(x)$ be some more general given function.

Comment: there are methods to solve this, but first, you need to do some searching on the internet.

Comment: I'd appreciate a source as an equally valid and useful answer in that case. If it's well known to others but not to me a reference would be great.

Comment: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/NonhomogeneousDE.aspx apart from the answer given.

Comment: I'd be especially interested in hyperbolic functions, like $g(x)=\tanh^nx$ and $g(x)=\operatorname{sech}^n x$, as special cases, but I'm interested in learning more about general cases as well.

Comment: these are general methods, so I don't think it will be any problem if you need hyperbolics or anything else.

Comment: If you know the Taylor expansion for $g$, you can try to define $f$ as another Taylor series and do some algebra. This approach is only practical for simple functions, though

Answer (score 2):

Here is one set of notes which seems useful

http://www.math.psu.edu/tseng/class/Math251/Notes-2nd%20order%20ODE%20pt1.pdf